# Transform Map<List<Long>,List<Long>> to String and Back

Tags: java, json, dictionary, serialization

I tried to do it with Gson, but you do not have to run the code to see that it does not make much sense:

```
final Map<List<Double>, List<Double>> map = new Gson().fromJson("{[111,222]=[333,444], [555,666]=[777,000]}", Map.class);
```

I get a MalformedJsonException. Has anybody an idea how to do this without having to create a custom class?

It must not be Json-related, also other approaches are welcome. And it has not to be a map, it can be a list of pairs, anyway I will never search using a list as a key, I will just iterate over it.

I am looking forward to reading your fresher ideas :)

Comment: It's not a valid JSON? Test it [HERE](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: The main point is not using Json, the main point is (de)serializing a Map (from)to a String.

Comment: Is your String format fixed ?

Comment: No, I just want that object in the end, the string can also look as a sha1 hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but could be used as a method to deserialize the string.
Serialization would be done with Gson.toJson(map).

```
    final Map<String, List<Double>> map = new Gson().fromJson("{\"[1,2,3,5]\"=[4,5,6]}", Map.class);
    final Map<List<Long>, List<Long>> result = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (final Map.Entry<String, List<Double>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        final List<Long> value = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (final Double number : entry.getValue()) {
            value.add(number.longValue());
        }
        final List<Double> rawKey = new Gson().fromJson(entry.getKey(), List.class);
        final List<Long> key = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (final Double number : rawKey) {
            key.add(number.longValue());
        }
        result.put(key, value);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON String is wrong for 2 reasons :

1. An array cannot be a key, i.e `[555,666]` invalid as a key
2. The symbol for associating a key with a value is `:` and not `=`

Comment: 1. I know that, that's why I was proposing to use alternatives to Json and wrote "does not make much sense"; 2. Wrong, with Gson you can also use = (at least for maps).

Comment: But if it's not JSON, it's just a format that does not exist, so you have to implement a custom parsing, maybe a grammar or a regexp.